# Ideal message size to get optimal throughput over TCP/IP

Tags: networking, tcp, packet, throughput

As you know, there are several variables that may impact the network throughput, something like windows size, packet size, number of bursts ...

I want to send messages of my own design over TCP/IP.

I know, there is no strict rule to detect the optimal message size for best throughput. However, would you please give me some notes that would help me optimize my throughput regarding *message size*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP doesn't have "messages", it's a *stream* protocol.

Just write your data in as large a chunk as possible, and let the network stack do the rest.

If ensuring that individual `write()` calls are processed as soon as possible is important, use the `TCP_NODELAY` socket option to disable the [Nagle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) (which otherwise will coalesce multiple small writes into a larger packet).

Comment: @Moi I already did - my point still stands.  Whilst it may be _convenient_ to think in terms of messages encapsulated within the stream, in practise TCP just doesn't work that way.

Comment: Ok, would you please explain more: What is "as large as possible" related to?